# Valid confidence intervals for AUC with very few cases?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, auc

**Situation:** I have a data set of patients who are positive for a certain illness. I also have a score for 1-year mortality from this illness, designed using a separate data set. The plan is to check the validity of this score on the patient data set. There are approximately 10 deaths and 1000 non-deaths in the data set.

**Questions:**

- With so few deaths, are any confidence intervals for the AUC valid?
- How many cases and non-cases does one need to attain valid confidence intervals?
- What method of estimating confidence intervals works best with skewed distribution and low cases counts? (Bootstrap?)

*(Feel free to offer partial answers!)*

**Thoughts:** The DeLong method relies on asymptotic normality of test statistics to generate confidence intervals. Thus, I would think a these CIs are only valid for sufficiently large samples, but I do not know how large. Alternatively, I know there are methods to construct bootstrap confidence intervals. But I don’t know what rules of thumb there are for when to use these.

Comment: Wojtek J. Krzanowski and David J. Hand's *ROC Curves for Continuous Data* (2009) is a great reference for all things related to ROC curves.